# Create instance of a class with arguments composed via MEF

Tags: .net, mef, composition

I have the following situation. In assembly A I have the following:

```
public class Service : IService
{
   private readonly IDependency dependency;

   public Service(IDependency dependency)
   {
       this.dependency = dependency;
   }
}
```

In assemblies B and C I have different implementations of `IDependency`:

```
[Export(typeof(IDependency)]
public class Dependency1 : IDependency { }

[Export(typeof(IDependency)]
public class Dependency2 : IDependency { }
```

How can I instruct MEF to create an instance of `Service` for each of the exported `IDependencies`?

Answer (score 2):

MEF does not support this out of the box. You have two options:

1. Presumably you planned to do an `[ImportMany(typeof(IService))]` somewhere to import all of the service instances. Instead, you could import a `ServiceProvider` object implemented like this:

   ```
   [Export]
   public class ServiceProvider
   {
       [ImportMany]
       public IEnumerable<IDependency> Dependencies { get; set; }

       public IEnumerable<IService> GetServices()
       {
          return Dependencies.Select(x => new Service(x));
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can augment MEF with your own export provider implementation. I've toyed with the idea of adding an `[ExportMany]` attribute which would be recognized by such a custom export provider. It seems to work, but it just a proof of concept. See https://bitbucket.org/wcoenen/mefexportmany/.

Answer (score 1):

As Wim has said, this isn't natively support out of the box. If you want to be able to do something like this:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<Service> _services { get; set; }
```

... without using a factory (such as the `ServiceProvider` detailed by Wim), then an export provider would work, e.g.:

```
public class ServiceExportProvider : ExportProvider
{
  private const string ContractName = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(typeof(Service));

  public ExportProvider SourceProvider { get; set; }

  protected override IEnumerable<Export> GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition def, AtomicComposition ac)
  {
    if (SourceProvider == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("SourceProvider property must be set.");

    if (def.ContractName.Equals(ContractName))
    {
      return SourceProvider
        .GetExports<IDependency>()
        .Select(e => new Export(def.ContractName, () => new Service(e.Value)));
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<Export>();
  }
}
```

You wouldn't need to `[Export]` your `Service` type (in fact that will likely cause problems), but you can `[Import]` and `[ImportMany]` of `Service` instances if you have registered with provider with your container, and set the `SourceProvider` property:

```
var catalog = // create catalogs/
var provider = new ServiceExportProvider();
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, provider);
provider.SourceProvider = container;
```